# SAS Input statement skipping a column reading from CSV file

Tags: csv, sas

```
data liquidity;
  infile '/home/loeeqsas/83.csv' dlm = ',' termstr=crlf dsd;
  input qid ddate date9. price vol af;
  adjprice=price*af;
  srtn=adjprice/lag1(adjprice)-1;
  dvol=adjprice*vol;

proc print data = liquidity;
run;
```

Output puts the price data in the vol column and shows price as blank. Is this to do with the date format? Thank you.

Comment: What is your question exactly? It is unclear in the current description

Comment: Please add an example of the 83.csv data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
input qid ddate date9. price vol af;
```

You can't put the informat that way without a colon.  Otherwise it will read incorrectly.  Either move it to an INFORMAT statement, or add a colon:

```
input qid ddate :date9. price vol af;
```